# How to pipe into std::cout with boost::iostreams

Tags: c++, boost, iostream, boost-iostreams

I am new to `boost::iostreams` so this might be trivial:

Assuming `namespace io = boost::iostreams;`

this works

```
io::filtering_ostream out(std::cout);
out << "some\nstring\n";
```

and this works

```
std::string result;
io::filtering_ostream out(io::counter() | io::back_inserter(result));
out << "some\nstring\n";
```

yet this does not compile

```
io::filtering_ostream out(io::counter() | std::cout);
out << "some\nstring\n";
```

How do you pipe into `std::cout`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrapping `std::cout` with [boost::ref](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/ref.html) worked for me:

```
io::filtering_ostream out(DummyOutputFilter() | boost::ref(std::cout));
```

See note_1 in [pipable docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/iostreams/doc/concepts/pipable.html#note_1) for details.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, a simple "Sink wrapper" looks like this:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/concepts.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/pipeline.hpp>

template<typename Sink>
class sink_wrapper
    : public boost::iostreams::device<boost::iostreams::output, typename Sink::char_type> {
public:
    sink_wrapper(Sink & sink) : sink_(sink) {}

    std::streamsize write(const char_type * s, std::streamsize n) {
        sink_.write(s, n);
        return n;
    }

private:
    sink_wrapper & operator=(const sink_wrapper &);
    Sink & sink_;
};
BOOST_IOSTREAMS_PIPABLE(sink_wrapper, 1)

template<typename S> sink_wrapper<S> wrap_sink(S & s) { return sink_wrapper<S>(s); }
```

And can be used like this:

```
boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream  out(filter | wrap_sink(std::cout));
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way you pass the stream. You have to use `push`:

```
out.push(std::cout);
```

Comment: Then why does the `back_inserter` work? Is there a "pipe" way to do it?

Comment: @3noch What does `back_inserter` have to do with it? That's not a stream, that's a device...

Comment: Is it not possible to convert a `std::stream` into a device? I'm expecting something like `make_device(std::cout)`.

Comment: @3noch I meant that it does not represent the Device *concept*. You can't actually create a device like that.

Comment: @3noch And are you looking for a "pipe" way of doing it simply to make your code shorter? Just curious. :)

Comment: My reasons for asking are 1) understanding the library better and 2) building the entire `io::ostream` at construction exactly as needed.

Comment: Could you not make something that models Device and wraps a `std::stream`? I would have expected something like that to already exist.